# How to get directly to text versions of Google cached pages

Tags: web-application, web-browser, ip, internet, caching

http://navigators.com/cached.html

According to the bottom of that site, it seems the easiest way to view websites without giving them your IP is:

"Edit the heck out" of google URLs like this:

Original:

webcache.googleusercontent.com / search ? q = cache : q73OkFyPlu4J : navigators.com / isp.html

Edited:

webcache.googleusercontent.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dcache%3Aq73OkFyPlu4J%3Anavigators.com%2Fisp.html_etc_etc_etc

This is so that you can see the text version of the cached site so never giving your IP. Well it has to be typed out manually and is a little tedius, and since this article was written in 2013, does anyone know of faster ways now?

(Using iPad if it matters)

Comment: If by "Edit the heck out" you mean "Append &strip=1 to the end of the cached page URL", then this is indeed the way to go.

Comment: It doesn't work any more. He says " Adding &strip=1 onto the end of a hijacked cached link does not work - you end up viewing a full version of the cached page with all of its embedded graphics, etc being downloaded by you directly  from the target website" :/ so you have to manually edit things like / to %2F

Comment: How is it related to IT security?

Comment: I don't know the use-case here, but one use-case is passive information gathering, ie. getting information from the Google cache and the Wayback Machine from a website without contacting the original website. And indeed due to a simple usability issue it does not appear easy to use Google cache in a really stealthy way.

Comment: @Deer Hunter,  I guess for the purpose of protecting your IP address ? :)

Comment: @GZBK hmm bummer :/

Comment: There are Greasemonkey scripts to strip fluff.

Comment: When you go with Firefox addon you can also use some specially crafted module like [Google search link fix](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-search-link-fix/?src=search) which will descramble Google results URL so you can easilly copy the cached page URL and, finally, simply add &strip=1 at the end. However, since this is browser specific and requires the installation of a specific addon, this remains nothing more than a workaround...